# How to mark one of RAID1 disks as a spare? (mdadm)

Tags: hard-disk, array, raid1

I have a healthy and working software based RAID1 using 3 HDDs as active on my Debian machine.

I want to mark one of the disks as a spare so it ends up being 2 active + 1 spare.

Things like:

```
mdadm --manage --raid-devices=2 --spare-devices=1 /dev/md0
```

and similar just fail saying either one of the options is not supported in current option mode or simply fails.

```
Billy@localhost~#: mdadm -G --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0
mdadm: failed to set raid disks
unfreeze
```

or

```
Billy@localhost~#: mdadm --manage --raid-devices=2 --spare-devices=1 /dev/md0
mdadm: :option --raid-devices not valid in manage mode
```

or similar. I have no idea man. please help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check the current state of the array with `cat /proc/mdstat`.  In this example, that's where the data comes from.

So let's assume we have `md127` with 3 disks in a raid1.  Here they're just partitions of one disk, but it doesn't matter

```
md127 : active raid1 vdb3[2] vdb2[1] vdb1[0]
      102272 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]
```

We need to offline one of the disks before we can remove it:

```
$ sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --fail /dev/vdb2
mdadm: set /dev/vdb2 faulty in /dev/md127
```

And the status now shows it's bad

```
md127 : active raid1 vdb3[2] vdb2[1](F) vdb1[0]
      102272 blocks super 1.2 [3/2] [U_U]
```

We can now remove this disk:

```
$ sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --remove /dev/vdb2
mdadm: hot removed /dev/vdb2 from /dev/md127

md127 : active raid1 vdb3[2] vdb1[0]
      102272 blocks super 1.2 [3/2] [U_U]
```

And now resize:

```
$ sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md127 --raid-devices=2
raid_disks for /dev/md127 set to 2
unfreeze
```

At this point we have successfully reduced the array down to 2 disks:

```
md127 : active raid1 vdb3[2] vdb1[0]
      102272 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

So now the new disk can be re-added as a hotspare:

```
$ sudo mdadm -a /dev/md127 /dev/vdb2
mdadm: added /dev/vdb2

md127 : active raid1 vdb2[3](S) vdb3[2] vdb1[0]
      102272 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

The `(S)` shows it's a hotspare.

We can verify this works as expected by failing an existing disk and noticing a rebuild takes place on the spare:

```
$ sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --fail /dev/vdb1
mdadm: set /dev/vdb1 faulty in /dev/md127

md127 : active raid1 vdb2[3] vdb3[2] vdb1[0](F)
      102272 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      [=======>.............]  recovery = 37.5% (38400/102272) finish=0.0min speed=38400K/sec
```

`vdb2` is no longer marked `(S)` because it's not a hotspare.

After the bad disk has been re-added *it* is now marked as the hotspare

```
md127 : active raid1 vdb1[4](S) vdb2[3] vdb3[2]
      102272 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You are the man.

I find it odd that you HAVE TO fail it first and there's no "switch" parameter or something. By the way, you also think running 3HDDs as **active** in RAID1 is probably a waste? Just want your opinion on whether I've done the right thing.

Comment: In a RAID-1 with 3 disks would keep all three active, rather than a hotspare, so that if there's a failure you _still_ have resilliency and don't need to wait for a rebuild.  2 active and 1 hotspare seems an odd configuration.